# How to avoid bounding check when index is surely in range?

Tags: go

I found code like this will still trigger bounding check(by adding `-gcflags="-d=ssa/check_bce/debug=1"`):

```
// slice is guaranteed to be non empty elsewhere

idx := someUintVariable % len(slice)

slice[idx] = someValue // Found IsInBounds, how to avoid that?
```

Is there a way to force the compiler not to do bounding check in this case?

Comment: _"slice is guaranteed to be non empty elsewhere"_ - please clarify exactly what "guarantee" is being made and how the compiler is supposed to know about it.

Comment: In my case it's a fixed sized `slice`, and it will panic if the size is 0. Let's assume the precondition holds.

Comment: Please post a full example we can paste in Godbolt.

Comment: I think there's no need for that, seudo code is enough, you've got what I want, what I'm seeking of is somewhat like the `unchecked` keyword in solidity, but I'm starting to believe that this feature is not available now in golang.

Comment: _"I think there's no need for that, pseudocode is enough"_ - **no, it isn't**: you're asking us about **specific compiler behaviour** but you haven't given us enough information to reproduce the _specific compiler behaviour_ you're describing. It's like asking a mechanic to fix an engine noise issue but refusing to let the repair-shop see your engine and instead insisting they diagnose the issue based on how well you can imitate the engine noises using your mouth and other bodily organs...

Comment: The language Spec https://go.dev/ref/spec is a 1h read and no, there is no "unchecked" keyword.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to force the compiler not to do bounding check in this case?

Only by disabling **all** bound checks with gcflags=-B.

There is no "inline flag" to turn off bound checking in just a single case.

Note that the compiler sometimes *can* prove to itself that the bound check cannot fail and thus drops the bound check. There is no reliable way to trigger this as this is an evolving implementation detail.